# Any way to have a common netlify.toml file for a single repository and multiple sites?

Tags: hugo, netlify

I'm looking out a way to define two site builds on netlify, sourced from the same repo, using a single common `netlify.toml`. Is it possible to do so?

I have a GitHub repository named [hugo-dream-plus](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/hugo-dream-plus) for which I've configured two website builds on netlify, namely `dream-plus-posts` and `dream-plus-cards`. Both of these builds share the same environment variables and mostly all of the configurations, except for the build commands:

```
hugo --config cards.toml     #For dream-plus-cards
hugo --config posts.toml     #For dream-plus-posts
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to create a common `netlify.toml` file, since the repo is the same for both builds, for both these sites.

> I've already used the web UI for configuring each build separately, but it's quite bothersome to modify each of them, that's why I'm preferring the above scenario.

What I plan to do is to have all configurations shared between the two builds except for the build command, which would be defined separately as shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the date of this answer, Netlify does not support a way to change values in the `netlify.toml`, because it is read in prior to your build. Except for the headers and redirects, which allow you to change at build.

> Using Environment Variables directly as values ($VARIABLENAME) in your netlify.toml file is not supported.

## However

You could run a script command and have it changed based on the domain or an environment variable. **There are a few setups that would work.**

Here is how I might accomplish what you want based on the domain name.

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "node ./scripts/custom.js"
  publish = "public"
```

`scripts/custom.js`

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const site = process.env.URL || "https://example.com";
const domain = site.split('/')[site.split('/').length - 1];

let buildCommand;
switch(domain) {
  case "dream-plus-posts.netlify.com":
    buildCommand = 'hugo --config posts.toml';
    break;
  case "dream-plus-cards.netlify.com":
    buildCommand = 'hugo --config cards.toml';
    break;
  default:
    throw `Domain ${domain} is invalid`;
}

async function execute(command){
  return await exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(`site: ${site}`);
    console.log(`domain: ${domain}`);
    console.log(stdout);
  });
};

execute(buildCommand);
```

#### *Things to note:*

- I did not test the stdout to the log using this method with Hugo. The child process captures the output and returns it in stdout.
- We don't want to capture errors, because we want our build to fail on errors so this will cause an exit code other than 0
- You can inline other commands with this solution (i.e. "node ./scripts/custom.js && some other command before deploy")
- You could also just check an environment variable you set rather than domain name

Comment: Thanks. This served as a good reference for me and also solved my problem. I didn't think of creating a custom build script, which, from now on, I will.

Comment: Great script, thanks! I ended up going for the environment variable route instead.